# How to get the response time in node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mean-stack

Recently I started putting response time to my API's.I tried putting to my routes but I am not sure how to use it.My aim is to get the response time in the console for each request.

```
var responseTime = require('response-time')
app.use(responseTime());
app.route('/getAllUsers').get(users.getUsers);
```

Can anyone please suggest help.Thanks.

Comment: I've never used response-time module, but I guess you should look at your headers response to see elapsed time.

Answer (score 2):

For getting the response time in your **routes** -

```
var start = new Date();

router.get('/dummy', function(req, res, next){
    console.log('Request took:', new Date() - start, 'ms');
});
```

output ex - *Request took: 1596 ms*

Comment: That shows the time between the start of the server and the time the request came in. Not very useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can [pass a function](https://github.com/expressjs/response-time#responsetimefn) that will get called after a request:

```
app.use(responseTime((req, res, time) => {
  console.log(req.method, req.url, time + 'ms');
}));
```

Or use a more elaborate logger middleware like [`morgan`](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan) that also provides the option to log response times.

Comment: Hi robertklep,how can I print timeslap for every http request i see in console.

Comment: I assume you mean timestamp? `console.log(new Date(), req.method, req.url, time + 'ms')`. But if you want that, I really recommend using a proper logging module like the aforementioned `morgan`.

Comment: I am trying to put timestamp for all requests that I see in the console.